# How can I sequentially apply different graph embeddings?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, lattices

Imagine I have some graph `G`, and I perform a graph embedding using a command like:

```
G = Graph[GraphEdges, GraphLayout -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding"}]
```

I then want to apply a `"GridEmbedding"` to the post-Spring/Electrical embedded graph.

How can I do this?

Specifically, I have a graph I know to be a rectangular lattice, but the vertices are at random positions initially.  Attempting a direct `"GridEmbedding"` yields junk; however the `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"` almost works, but begins to fail around the edges of the graph.  Does anyone have advice for dealing with this?

Alternatively, can `"GridEmbedding"` be made to respect edge lengths / weights akin to what is possible for `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129227/12) for embedding a perfect grid graph.  If the graph is not a perfect grid, this method won't work though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the one way:

```
g = Graph[RandomSample[EdgeList[GridGraph[{10, 12}]], 218], 
      GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {10, 12}}]
```

[image]

Apply SpringElectricalEmbedding to see how it work:

```
SetProperty[g, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Since you know your graph is rectangular, you can pick four corners by checking vertex degree.

```
In[356]:= corners = VertexList[g, x_ /; VertexDegree[g, x] == 2]
Out[356]= {111, 120, 10, 1}
```

Get possible tuples of corners:

```
In[357]:= tuples = Subsets[corners, {2}]
Out[357]= {{111, 120}, {111, 10}, {111, 1}, {120, 10}, {120, 1}, {10, 1}}
```

Generate shortest path function for further computation:

```
shortpath = FindShortestPath[g];
```

By checking lengths of paths between corners, you could find two boundary paths:

```
In[359]:= bound = shortpath @@@ tuples;
          {m, n} = Most[Sort[Union[Length /@ bound]]];
           paths = Select[bound, Length[#] == m &]
Out[361]= {{111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120}, {10, 9,
           8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}}
```

Compute grids of vertex indices:

```
pairs = If[Length[shortpath[paths[[1, 1]], paths[[2, 1]]]] == n,
   Transpose[paths], paths[[1]] = Reverse[paths[[1]]]; 
   Transpose[paths]];
grids = (VertexIndex[g, #] & /@ shortpath[##]) & @@@ pairs;
```

Compute coordinates using "SpringElectricalEmbedding":

```
coords = GraphEmbedding[g, "SpringElectricalEmbedding"];
```

Now straighten coords by the mean of each grid lines:

```
Table[coords[[i, 2]] = Mean[coords[[i, 2]]];, {i, grids}];
 Table[
coords[[i, 1]] = Mean[coords[[i, 1]]];, {i, Transpose[grids]}];
```

Here's the results:

```
SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> coords]
```

[image]

You could make function to do all steps:

```
gridCoordinates[g_] :=
   Block[{coords, corners, tuples, shortpath, bound, m, n, paths, pairs,
     grids},
    coords = GraphEmbedding[g, "SpringElectricalEmbedding"];
    corners = VertexList[g, x_ /; VertexDegree[g, x] == 2];
    tuples = Subsets[corners, {2}];
    shortpath = FindShortestPath[g];
    bound = shortpath @@@ tuples;
    {m, n} = Most[Sort[Union[Length /@ bound]]];
    paths = Select[bound, Length[#] == m &];
    pairs = If[Length[shortpath[paths[[1, 1]], paths[[2, 1]]]] == n,
              Transpose[paths], paths[[1]] = Reverse[paths[[1]]]; 
              Transpose[paths]];
    grids = (VertexIndex[g, #] & /@ shortpath[##]) & @@@ pairs;
    Table[coords[[i, 2]] = Mean[coords[[i, 2]]];, {i, grids}];
    Table[coords[[i, 1]] = Mean[coords[[i, 1]]];, {i, Transpose[grids]}];
    coords
   ]
```

Here's the version that generate coordinate on unit grid:

```
  gridUnitCoordinates[g_] :=
   Block[{coords, corners, tuples, shortpath, bound, m, n, paths, pairs,
     grids},
    corners = VertexList[g, x_ /; VertexDegree[g, x] == 2];
    tuples = Subsets[corners, {2}];
    shortpath = FindShortestPath[g];
    bound = shortpath @@@ tuples;
    {m, n} = Most[Sort[Union[Length /@ bound]]];
    paths = Select[bound, Length[#] == m &];
    pairs = If[Length[shortpath[paths[[1, 1]], paths[[2, 1]]]] == n,
              Transpose[paths], paths[[1]] = Reverse[paths[[1]]]; 
              Transpose[paths]];
    grids = (VertexIndex[g, #] & /@ shortpath[##]) & @@@ pairs;
    {m, n} = Dimensions[grids];
    coords = Flatten[Table[{j, i}, {i, m}, {j, n}], 1];
    coords[[Ordering[Flatten[grids]]]]
   ]
```

Comment: @halmir Very nice answer!  Is there a nice way to sort of map / snap the vertices in your output to a square / integer lattice?

Comment: @RogerHarris `Nearest` *may* work for that (haven't tried).  It'd be necessary to actually find a lattice with the correct dimensions for this to work well.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6835111/695132) may give ideas for that.

Comment: @halmir Why does your procedure only appear to work for a 10 x 12 integer lattice?

Comment: @RogerHarris what do you mean? it should work any integer lattice.. for example, m = 24; n = 32;
g = Graph[
  RandomSample[EdgeList[GridGraph[{m, n}]], 
   EdgeCount[GridGraph[{m, n}]]], 
  GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {m, n}}]