# How to find those missing edges in a grid graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to find a new method for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144576/how-to-make-a-graph-be-a-grid-layout-exactly).Suppose I have a such graph

```
graph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 17, 
   4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 9, 5 <-> 10, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 17, 7 <-> 12, 17 <-> 9, 
   17 <-> 13, 9 <-> 10, 9 <-> 14, 11 <-> 12, 11 <-> 16, 12 <-> 13, 
   12 <-> 8, 13 <-> 14, 13 <-> 18, 14 <-> 24, 14 <-> 19, 24 <-> 20, 
   16 <-> 8, 16 <-> 21, 8 <-> 18, 8 <-> 22, 18 <-> 19, 18 <-> 23, 
   19 <-> 20, 19 <-> 15, 20 <-> 25, 21 <-> 22, 21 <-> 26, 22 <-> 23, 
   22 <-> 27, 23 <-> 15, 23 <-> 28, 15 <-> 29, 25 <-> 30, 26 <-> 27, 
   27 <-> 28, 28 <-> 29, 29 <-> 30}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to find those missing edges,such as `{6<->11,10<->24,15<->25}`?

Comment: Let's make this more specific.  So you have a subgraph of a grid graph, where some of edges were dropped, but all of the vertices were kept?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes,it is exactly what want to express..

Comment: May `graph` be a subset of multiple grids, or is there enough edges for uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: @Coolwater Simple and undirected garph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only edges are missing, you can first generate a list of candidate grid graphs with the same number of nodes as in `graph`, then see which one contains `graph` as a subgraph. [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has subgraph finding functionality.

It could be derived from any of these grids, as they all have the same number of nodes:

```
candidateGrids =
 With[{vc = VertexCount[graph]},
  GridGraph[{#, vc/#}] & /@ Select[Divisors[vc], # <= Sqrt[vc] &]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Select the first one of these which contains `graph` as a subgraph:

```
<< IGraphM`
completeGrid = SelectFirst[candidateGrids, IGSubisomorphicQ[graph, #] &]
```

We can find one mapping between the vertices of `graph` and `completeGrid` using `IGVF2GetSubisomorphism`:

```
mapping = First@IGVF2GetSubisomorphism[graph, completeGrid]
(* <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 6 -> 6, 3 -> 3, 7 -> 7, 4 -> 4, 17 -> 8, 
 5 -> 5, 9 -> 9, 10 -> 10, 12 -> 12, 13 -> 13, 14 -> 14, 11 -> 11, 
 16 -> 16, 8 -> 17, 18 -> 18, 24 -> 15, 19 -> 19, 20 -> 20, 21 -> 21, 
 22 -> 22, 23 -> 23, 15 -> 24, 25 -> 25, 26 -> 26, 27 -> 27, 28 -> 28,
  29 -> 29, 30 -> 30|> *)
```

Then you can retrieve whatever you like: vertex coordinates, missing edges, etc.

```
coords = PropertyValue[{completeGrid, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
  Lookup[mapping, VertexList[graph]]

SetProperty[
 graph,
 VertexCoordinates -> Thread[VertexList[graph] -> coords]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or missing edges:

```
reverseMapping = Reverse /@ Normal[mapping];

missing =
 Block[{UndirectedEdge},
  SetAttributes[UndirectedEdge, Orderless];
  Complement[
   EdgeList[completeGrid] /. reverseMapping,
   EdgeList[graph]
   ]
  ]
(* {6 <-> 11, 10 <-> 24, 15 <-> 25} *)
```

(The `Orderless` attribute is temporarily set on UndirectedEdge to make sure that `a <-> b` is considered the same as `b <-> a`.)

```
HighlightGraph[
 VertexReplace[completeGrid, reverseMapping],
 missing,
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dashed",
 Options[completeGrid, GraphLayout]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

This will, of course, be quite slow due to the difficulty of finding subgraphs.  It will only work well for small grids like the one in your example.

To get *all* possible mappings instead of just one, use `IGVF2FindSubisomorphisms`. There will always be at least 4 possible mapping due to the symmetries of grid graphs.

Answer (score 5):

```
gg = GridGraph[{5, 6}, VertexLabels->"Name"];

isomorphisms = DeleteCases[FindGraphIsomorphism[graph, #] & /@ 
     (EdgeDelete[gg, #] & /@ 
      Subsets[EdgeList[gg], {EdgeCount[gg] - EdgeCount[graph]}]), {}];
vmap = First@MinimalBy[Join@@DeleteCases[Normal @ isomorphisms, Rule[x_, x_], 3], Length];

ed = Complement[EdgeList[gg], EdgeList[graph] /. vmap]
```

> {6 <-> 11, 10 <-> 15, 24 <-> 25}

```
SetProperty[VertexReplace[EdgeDelete[gg, ed], vmap], 
 {VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {5, 6}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just one question,I dont' know that dimension `{5, 6}` in some larger graph by a glance.

Answer (score 2):

The graph is a subgraph of same dimension grid graph.
The basic idea is to find the corresponding grid graph's edges which are not in the subgraph's edge list.

If it's necessary, please refer to [How to make a graph be a grid layout exactly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144576/how-to-make-a-graph-be-a-grid-layout-exactly/144729#144729)

In:

```
xss = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 17, 4 <-> 5,
    4 <-> 9, 5 <-> 10, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 17, 7 <-> 12, 17 <-> 9, 
   17 <-> 13, 9 <-> 10, 9 <-> 14, 11 <-> 12, 11 <-> 16, 12 <-> 13, 
   12 <-> 8, 13 <-> 14, 13 <-> 18, 14 <-> 24, 14 <-> 19, 24 <-> 20, 
   16 <-> 8, 16 <-> 21, 8 <-> 18, 8 <-> 22, 18 <-> 19, 18 <-> 23, 
   19 <-> 20, 19 <-> 15, 20 <-> 25, 21 <-> 22, 21 <-> 26, 22 <-> 23, 
   22 <-> 27, 23 <-> 15, 23 <-> 28, 15 <-> 29, 25 <-> 30, 26 <-> 27, 
   27 <-> 28, 28 <-> 29, 29 <-> 30};
graph = Graph[xss, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

(*thanks for yode's code to get the dimension*)

spiralGraph = Graph[xss, GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding"];
dimension = 
  Length@*Union /@ Transpose[GraphEmbedding[spiralGraph]] // Reverse;

rules = xss // Map[First] // DeleteDuplicates // {#, Sort[#]} & // 
  MapThread[Rule, #] & (*Vertex\[Rule]Index Rules*)

List @@@ (xss /. rules) // UndirectedEdge @@@ # & // 
 Graph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &

(*Transformed subgraph*)
sg = 
 List @@@ (xss /. rules) // UndirectedEdge @@@ # & // 
  Graph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &
(*Grid Graph*)
gg = GridGraph[dimension, VertexLabels -> Reverse@rules]

{gg, sg} // Map[EdgeList] // Sequence @@ # & // Complement // 
 Map[# /. rules &]
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I just always fail to understand your `xss // Map[First] // DeleteDuplicates // {#, Sort[#]} &`..though I have to say this is very usefull method.

Comment: not bad, thanks for the Pallette!

Comment: @yode, The idea is easier than the implementation. :)