# Generating a weighted oriented lattice

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, code-request, lattices

I have a periodic lattice, and I would like to associate some phase parameters connecting to the neighbors that can be thought of as a hopping parameter.

Now the choice of these phase parameters is not completely arbitrary. The question is all about the choice of these parameters for a particular lattice.

I illustrate my point with an example. Let us consider for simplicity a square lattice with 25 sites, as shown below.
[image]

The above lattice can also be thought a graph where the edges connect neighboring nodes. The condition for the phase parameters can be seen by choosing a plaquette (or face of a graph). Let us consider the plaquette formed by lattice sites `1`, `2`, `9`, `8`. Then we associate a parameter to the links (or edges). If a particle hop (or goes) from `1` to `2`, it is $b$, if it goes from `2` to `9`, it is $c$, if it goes from `9` to `8`, it is $d$ and if it goes from `8` back to `1`, it is $a$. Then these phase parameters should add up to a value let us say $\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha = b + c + d + a $. Most importantly, the direction (or orientation) of the particle hopping is very crucial. If we go from, let us say, `1` to `8`, then the phase parameter is $-a$, and so on so forth. This whole idea of orientation is essentially illustrated in the below figure, where we consider clockwise orientation.
[image]
Now the system has periodic boundary conditions, which are shown by the colored boundaries. The same color corresponds to the same boundary. Thus this phase parameter choice should still be respected, as shown for plaquette `4-5-16-15` and `7-8-23-22`.

Coding part (my logic):

1. I have a matrix $M_{hop}$ that generates the above lattice or any lattice of size $N$, where $N$ is the number of nodes or lattice sites. In the above case, it is 25. Then $M_{hop}$ is $N\times N$.
2. Then, I can find all the plaquettes or faces of the periodic lattices using `FindCycles`.
3. Orienting all the cycles (clockwise in the above case) in such a way that the above-discussed condition is met.
4. Then we have set equations $=$ the number of plaquettes in the lattice. They can be solved using `FindInstance`, since many possible solution might exist, so one is fine. In the above case, these equations were $\alpha = b + c + d + a $, $\alpha = e + f + g - a $, $\alpha = h + i + j - g $, $\alpha = k + l + m - i $, so on so forth. Thus, addition of all parameters inside each plaquette in right orientation should add to $\alpha$.
5. Then, I will have a new $M_{hop}$, which is a function of only $\alpha$, no more any parameters.

My MWE:

```
mhop={{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};

 FindCycle[mhop,{4},All]
```

I have no idea how to take into account the orientation that will be general, that means for nay kind lattice with any number of sides with any lattice numbering. My guess is to use `ConnectedComponets` mostly used in graph stuffs.

Comment: I have an attempt - I'm a little unsure if you want to use a graph or matrix? If matrix - when you chose a particle to hop, you can multiply the parameter by the difference between the particle site indices ~ if it moves left it will be *-1

Comment: cool problem!! to be clear, `mhop` is an adjacency matrix? also, will you ever have non-grid-like lattices? if not, @Teabelly 's implicitly-mentioned matrix encoding, e.g. `mhop = {{17, 16, 15, ...}, ...}` might offer speedups. (periodicity can be achieved without too much fuss.)

Comment: I have a solution, but it depends on how you want to implement step 3 in your setup, since as you know `FindCycle` doesn't know "which orientation" to find the plaquette in. That is, if you naively try to turn one of the resulting cycles into an equation, you don't know whether the corresponding sum should be equal to $\alpha$ or $-\alpha$. I think you might need a different data structure that implicitly encodes orientation, or a way of determining the orientation of each cycle. So, this depends on whether you can stick to grid-like lattices or need more generality!

Comment: oh wait. I just realized that for the periodic lattice given, it will be mathematically impossible to find a set of such weights if $\alpha \neq 0$. Consider the sum of the edge weights over all plaquettes. if there are $n$ plaquettes, then this sum should be $n\alpha$. But since for every term in this sum, the negative of the term also appears in the sum (via the other plaquette), this sum must be 0, and so $n\alpha=0$. Unless we're working in an atypical ring, e.g. one of nonzero characteristic, we must have $\alpha=0$. Is $\alpha$ allowed to vary with each plaquette?

Comment: @Teabelly My big apologies for getting back late, many conferences these days. Anyways, I want a matrix at the end with parameter $\alpha$. How do we decide this left and right in arbitrary lattice is tricky.

Comment: @thorimur My big apologies for getting back late, many conferences these days. Anyways, you're right `mhop` is an adjacency matrix. Yup, my lattices are of grid type. I might not have comprehend the @Teabelly's point completely.

Comment: @thorimur that is a big problem in my case that the `FindCycle` doesn't know, as you clearly said. How I want to implement my step third can be thought more of logic, if we choose an edge and we decide some value `a` in one direction, then we can choose it `-a` in another direction by noting that it is shared between to the cycles. So if we choose one convention then we can extend from one cycle to another and then to whole of the lattice.\

Comment: @ You have nail down the problem. You are right, it is impossible to get a same consistent $\alpha$ throught each cycles with right orientation. However, in one of the cycles, we can have $\alpha = 2\pi$, that might solve the problem. This \alpha is a variable but it can take value from $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: As a lattice field theorist it’s remarkable to watch non-experts begin to redevelop the field from scratch in these comments . @Shamina, do you always have a regular (or at least structured), planar, 2D graph?  Don’t use mma to rediscover the grid structure (plaquettes+orientations)—determine that structure given N.  The key to making this easy is to number the sites not in a spiral but in an easier order, like left-to-right top-to-bottom.  If you’re planning on large-scale simulations that choice will also make your eventual C/FORTRAN MPI communications addressing much simpler.

Comment: @Shamina no problem! (after all, I've been kind of busy too!) hmmm...you say $\alpha$ can take values in $[0, 2\pi]$. It wouldn't happen to be *modulo* $2\pi$, would it?  That would fundamentally change the nature of the solutions in a useful way, as we could have e.g. $\alpha = a + b + c + d = \pi/2 + \pi/2 + \pi/2 + \pi/2 = 0 (\mod 2\pi)$, which could give us a lot of wiggle room. just thought i'd check!

Comment: @evanb It is interesting indeed. I didn't know before, a constant $\alpha$ inside each plaquette is not possible but I'm sure you may know the deeper reason about it. And I would be very glad to hear that, it will be enlightening for me!  Yup, it is always a regular map. Ok, it can also be not regular, like in the above case of square lattice without periodic boundary conditions. Seeing beyond MMA sounds very interesting, I didn’t think about it, I can tell you somewhere the distinction of left-to-right top-to-bottom can be tricky for some lattice structures (hexagons) if understand you well.

Comment: @thorimur You are getting far more closer to the problem solution, it seems :)  You are right. That is all about the range of $\alpha$, and it is true it is only uniquely defined in that interval—that why I referred to it as a phase parameter in the problem. Yeah, I was not clear before, but you are right.

Comment: @Shamina If what you are doing is trying to implement a U(1) gauge theory, let me advise you to contact me by email (my website is in my profile; look at the contact page).  The main problem you will face with your construction is that it looks like you're putting the Lie algebra elements (the angles θ) on the links.  At any finite lattice spacing this will generate relevant gauge-variant operators and require you to fine-tune the parameters of your simulation.  Instead consider putting Lie group elements (e^iθ) on the links.

Comment: @evanb Sure, I will try to contact you. I was trying to understand your point better, maybe I didn't comprehend it completely. But the $\theta$ = $a,b,c,d,...$? If yes, then my $a,b,c,d,...$ are essentially $e^{i a},..$. However, this problem still persists.

Answer (score 5):

To generate a graph

```
graph[n_] := Graph[Flatten[
Table[{Nest[Reverse, {i, j} \[DirectedEdge] {Mod[i + 1, n + 1], j},
   Mod[1 + i + j, 2]], 
 Nest[Reverse, {i, j} \[DirectedEdge] {i, Mod[j + 1, n + 1]}, 
  Mod[i + j, 2]]}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}], 2], 
VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Table[{i, 
   j} -> {Cos[2 \[Pi] i/(n + 1)] (2 + Cos[2 \[Pi] j/(n + 1)]), 
   Sin[2 \[Pi] i/(n + 1)] (2 + Cos[2 \[Pi] j/(n + 1)]), 
   Sin[2 \[Pi] j/(n + 1)]}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}], 1]]
limitedsymboltable[l_List] := Transpose@{l,Symbol /@ 
  Join[Alphabet[],StringJoin /@ Partition[Flatten[
  Riffle[Alphabet[], #] & /@ Alphabet[]],2]][[;; Length@l]]}
```

so your example would be something like `GraphPlot[graph@3,EdgeLabels->Rule@@@limitedsymboltable@EdgeList@graph@3]`,

[image: labelledtorusgraph3d]

By the way, `limitedsymboltable` is unsafe since what if those symbols are already being used...  Also it only supports lists with up to 689 elements; generality is difficult.

Anyway, let's make a function to construct those equations.  I'm not sure about `FindCycles`, so I'll just construct all the plaquettes explicitly

```
squares[n_] := 
 Join @@ Table[{{i, j}, {i, Mod[j + 1, n + 1]}, {Mod[i + 1, n + 1], 
 Mod[j + 1, n + 1]}, {Mod[i + 1, n + 1], j}}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, 
  n}]
```

These squares have predictable orientations.  Now

```
sign[graph_, v1_, v2_] := 
 Count[EdgeList@graph, v1 \[DirectedEdge] v2] - 
 Count[EdgeList@graph, v2 \[DirectedEdge] v1]
```

and

```
eqns[n_] := 
 With[{g = graph@n, s = squares@n}, 
  With[{st = limitedsymboltable[List @@@ EdgeList@g]}, 
   With[{e2s = AssociationThread @@ 
   Transpose@Join[st, {Reverse@#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@st]},
    {"equations" -> (\[Alpha] == 
      e2s@{#[[1]], #[[2]]} sign[g, #[[1]], #[[2]]] + 
      e2s@{#[[2]], #[[3]]} sign[g, #[[2]], #[[3]]] - 
      e2s@{#[[3]], #[[4]]} sign[g, #[[3]], #[[4]]] - 
      e2s@{#[[4]], #[[1]]} sign[g, #[[4]], #[[1]]] & /@ 
    squares@n), "bidiedgestosymbols" -> e2s}]]]
```

I must admit, `eqns` is a bit nasty.  Works though: `"equations"/.eqns@3` yields

```
{\[Alpha] == -a + b + c - j, \[Alpha] == c - d - e + l, 
 \[Alpha] == -e + f + g - n, \[Alpha] == -a + g - h + p,
 \[Alpha] == i - j - k + r, \[Alpha] == -k + l + m - t, 
 \[Alpha] == m - n - o + v, \[Alpha] == i - o + p - x, 
 \[Alpha] == -q + r + s - z, \[Alpha] == ba + s - t - u, 
 \[Alpha] == -da - u + v + w, \[Alpha] == fa - q + w - x, 
 \[Alpha] == -aa + b + y - z, \[Alpha] == -aa + ba + ca - d, 
 \[Alpha] == ca - da - ea + f, \[Alpha] == -ea + fa - h + y}
```

Now to solve them for a particular $\alpha$

```
FindInstance["equations"/.#/.\[Alpha]->5,Values["bidiedgestosymbols"/.#]]&@eqns@3
```

Unfortunately, this gives trivial solutions where most of the edges are zero.  We could try to find useful relations with

```
Reduce["equations"/.#,Append[Values["bidiedgestosymbols"/.#],\[Alpha]]]&@eqns@3
```

but at this point I think I'm using Mathematica in a slightly strange and perverted way.

---

I can't resist including a way of numbering vertices in a spiral as you have done:

```
squarespiral[n_, j_ : -1] := Graph[Range@((2 n - 1)^2), 
 Join[# \[UndirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[4 n (n - 1)], 
   2 + # - 2 \[LeftCeiling]Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling] + 
   Mod[\[LeftCeiling]2 Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling], 2]
    \[UndirectedEdge] 
   2 + # - 2 \[LeftCeiling]Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling] + 
   Mod[\[LeftCeiling]2 Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling], 2] + 
   2 \[LeftFloor]Sqrt[4 # - 3]\[RightFloor] + 1 & /@ 
   Range[4 (n - 1)^2]][[;; Mod[j, 8 n^2 - 12 n + 5]]]]
```

This has 1 connected to 2 connected to etc. in a spiral, and then fills in the 'rail road ties' with some not-too-complicated math.  Let's animate that explanation by simply incrementing `j`:

[image: gif]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this nice answer! But square lattice was a very simple example of my actual case. For research reasons, I was unable to give, actually, my actual `mhop`. It is bit more complicated than our beautiful square lattice, but it is still a lattice. I think some of the aspects can not be straightforwardly generalized, at at least the plaquettes, that's why it is easy for me to read them from the `mhop` directly.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you'll want to generalize the underlying graph anyway, so I'll use a  toroidal square lattice for illustration purposes, since it's simple to construct and very similar to your periodic grid (and in particular has 4-cycles defining plaquettes):

```
ToroidalGraph[n_] := Graph@Flatten@Table[{v[i, j] \[UndirectedEdge] v[i, Mod[j + 1, n, 1]], v[i, j] \[UndirectedEdge] v[Mod[i + 1, n, 1], j]}, {i, n}, {j, n}]

n=5;
g = ToroidalGraph@n
```

[image: toroidal]

The vertices are named `v[i,j]` where `i` is the row number and `j` is the column number. You could define this function to number them from `1` to `n^2`, but we don't really need to do that for what follows. In any case, you should be able to drop in here any (undirected) graph of your choice.

We'll be using `FindCycle` to find 4-cycles defining plaquettes. This function returns paths, *i.e.* lists of edges, so we need a function to build equations from paths:

```
BuildEquation[\[Alpha]_][path_] := \[Alpha] == Sum[c[edge], {edge, path}]
```

This function takes the target value of alpha and a path, and sums the costs of all edges in the path, requiring them to add up to alpha. How can we tell if the edge is transversed in the "positive" or the "negative" direction? Because this is entirely conventional, we'll define `c[u \[UndirectedEdge] v]` to include a negative sign if `u > v`:

```
c[u_ \[UndirectedEdge] v_] /; ! OrderedQ@{u, v} := -c[v \[UndirectedEdge] u]
```

(Note that our nodes are not numbered, but we can still use `OrderedQ` to determine if their labels are in a canonical order. Also note that you can replace `OrderedQ` by any function you want to use to determine where minus signs should appear in your equations, if you have particular preferences.)

The variables in this problem are then the costs of transversing each edge:

```
vars = c /@ Sort /@ EdgeList@g;
```

Note that we sort the (undirected) edges to make sure our variable list contains no minus signs (you'll need to be careful here if you replace `OrderedQ` above!).

We'll get the equations from `FindCycle` as previously mentioned. In this graph there are `n^2` nodes and `2n^2` edges, with each plaquette having `4` edges and each edge contributing to `2` plaquettes, resulting in `n^2` plaquettes. For reasons mentioned in the comments, no solution should exist for non-zero alpha, and Mathematica's `FindInstance` will default to the trivial solution for vanishing alpha, so for illustration purposes we'll take alpha equal to `1` and omit one equation to have a feasible system:

```
eqs = BuildEquation[1] /@ FindCycle[g, {4}, n^2-1];
```

Then we get

```
FindInstance[eqs, vars, Integers]
(*{{c[v[1, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[1, 2]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 1]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[1, 3]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 2]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[1, 4]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 3]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[1, 5]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 4]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[1, 5]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 5] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 5]] -> 0, 
  c[v[2, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 2]] -> 1, 
  c[v[2, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 1]] -> 0, 
  c[v[2, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 3]] -> 1, 
  c[v[2, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 2]] -> 0, 
  c[v[2, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 4]] -> 1, 
  c[v[2, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 3]] -> 0, 
  c[v[2, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 5]] -> 1, 
  c[v[2, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 4]] -> 0, 
  c[v[2, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[2, 5]] -> 1, 
  c[v[2, 5] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 5]] -> 0, 
  c[v[3, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 2]] -> 2, 
  c[v[3, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 1]] -> 0, 
  c[v[3, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 3]] -> 2, 
  c[v[3, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 2]] -> 0, 
  c[v[3, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 4]] -> 0, 
  c[v[3, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 3]] -> 0, 
  c[v[3, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 5]] -> 0, 
  c[v[3, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 4]] -> 0, 
  c[v[3, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[3, 5]] -> 2, 
  c[v[3, 5] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 5]] -> 0, 
  c[v[4, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 2]] -> 1, 
  c[v[4, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 1]] -> 0, 
  c[v[4, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 3]] -> 1, 
  c[v[4, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 2]] -> 0, 
  c[v[4, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 4]] -> -1, 
  c[v[4, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 3]] -> 0, 
  c[v[4, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 5]] -> 1, 
  c[v[4, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 4]] -> 0, 
  c[v[4, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[4, 5]] -> 1, 
  c[v[4, 5] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 5]] -> 0, 
  c[v[5, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 2]] -> 2, 
  c[v[1, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 1]] -> 0, 
  c[v[5, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 3]] -> -1, 
  c[v[1, 2] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 2]] -> 3, 
  c[v[5, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 4]] -> 0, 
  c[v[1, 3] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 3]] -> 1, 
  c[v[5, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 5]] -> 2, 
  c[v[1, 4] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 4]] -> 2, 
  c[v[5, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 5]] -> 2, 
  c[v[1, 5] \[UndirectedEdge] v[5, 5]] -> 3}}*)
```

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fidel! I took all time to go through your code deeply and trying to understand it better, as it seems to be more closer to my requirements. However, I think `c[u_ \[UndirectedEdge] v_]` cannot be generalized to more general cases? For e.g. let us consider Icosohedron, i.e., `g=GraphData["IcosahedralGraph"]`, then we do not find any solutions. I guess it is related to the fact of `c` maybe?

Comment: You're welcome, @Shamina! I believe the definition of `c[u_ \[UndirectedEdge] v_]` is quite general: at the most abstract level, we are assigning a value to each edge of the graph when transversed in the `u->v` direction, and its negative when transversed in the `v->u` direction; we are then writing equations for some paths on the graph, and in each path the edges are transversed in one direction or the other, but there's no other option...

Comment: When changing the graph `g`, there are two basic ingredients we need to consider, both appearing in the definition of `eqs`: one is the length of the cycles we are looking for, and the other is the number of equations we want to pose. The natural choice for `g=GraphData["IcosahedralGraph"]` is to take cycles of length 3, of which there are 20; if we take all 20 equations, however, we'll find no solutions for non-vanishing alpha, so we can drop one equation and take 19, i.e. `eqs = BuildEquation[1] /@ FindCycle[g, {3}, 19]`, and this is enough to find non-trivial solutions...

Comment: Finally, let me point out that there is an intrinsic arbitrariness in the way the equations are built, since in an undirected graph you can reverse any cycle at the cost of a minus sign in the right hand side of your equation. This suggests that non-vanishing values of alpha shouldn't be "physical". For planar graphs you can of course make some arbitrary rule to fix directions, e.g. turn clockwise around each face, but this does not extend to general graphs, and more importantly means there will be no solutions with non-zero alpha (because each edge will appear once in each direction).

Comment: I checked your code with many graphs, it works fabulously! I have a very last question, is it possible to express the solution of edges in terms of `α`? Like, `c[1-2]= k1 α`,.., so on for each of the edges, where `k1s` are some constants after solving in terms of `α`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think I have resolved the problem, so you can ignore it! Many thanks again!

Comment: @Shamina I guess the easiest way to do this is to just take alpha equals to 1, so that the coefficients on the right hand side of all equations are measured in units of alpha? Anyway, glad my answer was helpful, and thanks for the bounty :-)

Comment: I think there is a minor mistake in the code, which I couldn't convince myself before ;) I'm sure you can correct it. The problem is `c` somehow cannot fix the orientation problem, as I mentioned to you before, but I was very incoherent. To better understand, let us take `g=AdjacencyGraph[
 SparseArray[(# + Transpose[#]) &[
   ArrayFlatten[
    Table[KroneckerDelta[xi + 1, xj] KroneckerDelta[yi, yj] + 
      KroneckerDelta[yi + 1, yj] KroneckerDelta[xi, xj], {xi, l}, {xj,
       l}, {yi, l}, {yj, l}]]]]]`.

Comment: And then we can follow your nicely explained code. However, there is problem in the orientation. In some plaquettes, going counter clockwise gives `α`, and in some clockwise. It would be a problem for my later cases. In this example. if you calculate it for the two plaquettes, namely, counter clockwise direction with lattice positions(i,j): [[1, 11]] + [[11, 12]] + [[12, 2]] + [[2, 1]] we get `α` but when we take lattice positions for another plaquette in clockwise `[[12, 22]] + [[22, 23]] + [[23, 13]] + [[13, 12]]` it also comes `α` instead of `-α`. Any help from your side is thanked billion

Comment: @Shamina Indeed, the overall sign of the equations depends on the order of the edges found by `FindCycle`. I believe it's non-trivial to define what "counter-clockwise orientation around a face" means in a general graph, so I skipped this in my solution to keep things simple. You'll probably need to add some additional structure to your graph (e.g. a jacket to embed it on an oriented Riemann surface), and then use this to pre-process cycles before building equations, like so: `eqs = BuildEquation[1] /@ OrientCycles /@ FindCycle[g, {4}, n^2-1];`. This, however, is a completely different problem

Comment: Exactly, so my question can we do this in your above code?that's whole my question was about, else it will make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I like to start with the foundations of Wolfram Mathematica and Wolfram Language. Graphs are part of this from the very beginning. There were a lot of changes up to the most modern versions.

As can be found in the documentation of [`GridGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridGraph.html) an option make a [`GridGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridGraph.html) directed:

`GridGraph[{Subscript[n, 1],Subscript[n, 2],\[Ellipsis],Subscript[n, k]},DirectedEdges->True]` gives a directed grid graph.

So You're very much appreciated question targets a built-in directly.

I did some research for the question and found [given a lattice graph without spatial embedding how to identify the location of nodes in a lattice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129156/given-a-lattice-graph-without-spatial-embedding-how-to-identify-the-location-of/129227#129227). I state it at the very first sight as closely related.

What You wish to do is change this canonic enumeration into one centered in a most probably hand picked vertice and reenumerated the graph in a spiraling form. You do not intent to stick to equilateral graph but prefer to introduce `a, b, c, d` as independent form parameters.

The built-in allows You to assign arbitrary vertices enumeration like and random grid boundary length to each side of each grid square as long as they still remain to build a grid:

```
GridGraph[{5, 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexCoordinates -> 
  Flatten[Table[{j + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], 
     5 - i + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}], 1], 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

The spiral offered by [@adam](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/74641/adam) is based only on edge enumeration. That is a beautiful simplification and leaves to Mathematica the internals required by the set of `{a, b, c, d}` shown in Your questions simplifying pictures. This preferentially demands a solution in vertices coordinates.

A notebook by [PrimeSpiral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSpiral.html) by Eric Weisstein and the disambiguation page above that [Spirals](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/Spirals.html) show up the problem to define what spiral type is meant if only an example is given. A solution can be found on [VertexCoordinates](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html)

```
spiral[n_] := 
 Table[(1/2 (-1)^  # ({1, -1} (Abs[#^  2 - t] - #) + #^  2 - t - 
        Mod[#, 2]) &)[Round[Sqrt[t]]], {t, 0, n}]
```

and in a pimped version

```
CycleGraph[50, VertexCoordinates -> spiral[49], DirectedEdges -> True,
```

VertexLabels -> "Name"]]

[image: solution for the center start from Mathematica documentation]

Mind this is a closed graph due to better math.

```
spiralpertubed[n_] := 
 Table[(1/2 (-1)^# ({1, -1} (Abs[#^2 - t] - #) + #^2 - t - 
         Mod[#, 2]) &)[Round[Sqrt[t]]], {t, 0, n}] + 
  Table[{+RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}], +RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {t, 0, 
    n}]

CycleGraph[50, VertexCoordinates -> spiralpertubed[49], 
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: pertubed solution]

This much more complicated than using just the set of constants but it is already as an individual to the cells, former square as in Your last picture.

The generalization to square grid graphs goes over

```
ss0 = squarespiral@3

vc0 = AbsoluteOptions[ss0, VertexCoordinates][[1, 2]]

squarespiralpertubed[n_, vc1, j_: - 1] := 
 Graph[Range@((2 n - 1)^2), 
  Join[# \[UndirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[4 n (n - 1)], 
    2 + # - 2 \[LeftCeiling]Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling] + 
        Mod[\[LeftCeiling]2 Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling], 
         2] \[UndirectedEdge] 
       2 + # - 2 \[LeftCeiling]Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling] + 
        Mod[\[LeftCeiling]2 Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling], 2] + 
        2 \[LeftFloor]Sqrt[4 # - 3]\[RightFloor] + 1 & /@ 
     Range[4 (n - 1)^2]][[;; Mod[j, 8 n^2 - 12 n + 5]]], 
  VertexCoordinates -> vc1, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

example:

```
squarespiralperturbed[3, vc1]
```

[image: perturbed solution]

The option `VertexCoordinates` allows perturbing the square positions flexibly.

An individual color can only be assigned with a static color list like

```
esf0 = {#, RandomColor[], Thick} & /@ EdgeList[%29]
```

if %29 is an input of the squaresprialperturbed.

```
squarespiralpertubedg[n_, vc1_, esf0_, jj_: - 1] := 
 Graph[Range@((2 n - 1)^2), 
  Join[# \[UndirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[4 n (n - 1)], 
    2 + # - 2 \[LeftCeiling]Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling] + 
        Mod[\[LeftCeiling]2 Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling], 
         2] \[UndirectedEdge] 
       2 + # - 2 \[LeftCeiling]Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling] + 
        Mod[\[LeftCeiling]2 Sqrt[#]\[RightCeiling], 2] + 
        2 \[LeftFloor]Sqrt[4 # - 3]\[RightFloor] + 1 & /@ 
     Range[4 (n - 1)^2]][[;; Mod[jj, 8 n^2 - 12 n + 5]]], 
  VertexCoordinates -> vc1, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeStyle -> esf0]
```

Your `mhop` matrice must be used as a graph in the built-in `FindCycle`. The direct use is not permissible with Mathematica. A possible path is

```
AdjacencyGraph[mhop]
```

[image: use mhop in the built-in FindCycle]

mhop is not a valid incidence matrice.

```
FindCycle[AdjacencyGraph[mhop], {4}, All]
```

[image: found cycles]

These are all cycles of four vertices. The graph looks very like the one from [@fidel-i-schaposnik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45839/fidel-i-schaposnik)!. The four cycle are all given in the pictures of Your question. The order of the cycles is from outside to the inner most vertice one. So the given `mhop` matrice represents the spiral very well if not exact and independent of the vertice coordinates and the individual set `{a, b, c, d}`.

There is nothing to be visualized for that.

```
{VertexCount[%3], EdgeCount[%3]}
```

{25, 50}

The interpretation of the adjacency matrice is each edge is represented in a binary logical manner with 1 if there is an edge between the vertice numbered with the column and row indices. The built-in [`AdjacencyGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html) transforms that matrice into a graph back again. For n even bigger this becomes very large. There is no other way than that given by [@adam](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/74641/adam) to describe the vertices crisp is this grid graph fashion. That is because I started with the improvement of his answer. From [AdjacencyMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html) You can connect the grid graph spiral enumeration to the $M_{hop}$ matrix of Your question. Your $\alpha$ is always 4 because the length a selected by the visualization engine for graphs in the notebooks of Mathematica or WolframCloud.

Just in the situation of absolute edge length given in the graph description the situation changes towards an $\alpha$ or even an $\alpha_{i}$ for each square or cell. But Mathematica is not that flexible it takes some effort to produce nice graphs again if absolute length are selected and entered. Mathematica has some poor fame in not drawing graphs very accurate or even to scale.

Some experience can be gathered by search this StackExchange blog. For example [drawing a graph with specified edge lengths](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/drawing-a-graph-with-specified-edge-lengths). [@halmir](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/590/halmir) calls this behaviour as approximate using [`EdgeWeight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeWeight.html). This works even with symbolics and operates well behaved.

As can be seen on [WeightedAdjacencyMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyMatrix.html) even with weights selected arbitrary Mathematica only show the adjacency graph and it is best to write the weights on the edges. Since there are only for edges in each row a row sum on the [WeightedAdjacencyMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyMatrix.html) will be your $\alpha_{i}$.

It in no more complicated than this. I leave the impression to [WeightedAdjacencyMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyMatrix.html) in the Mathematica documentation. Mathematica presents in contrast [GraphLayout](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html) options. The use of [VertexCoordinates](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html) is cleaner and visual more crisp and flexible.

I hope this helps and may You are ready for an iterative and interactive step to improve my answer. I hope so far a fair cohesion and coherence to this blog and Your question is matched. Thanks a lot.

To some impression of how I percive Your answer and connect it to previous question from other similar to Yours work Yourself through the answers found by Google: [graphs with absolute edge lengths mathematica](https://www.google.com/search?q=graphs%20with%20absolute%20edge%20lengths%20mathematica&safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk00CJRWFtkvIGB659VHbL3IgGHVfvw%3A1623007174281&ei=xh-9YOW7EOeO9u8Pv6iM4AE&oq=graphs%20with%20absolute%20edge%20lengths%20mathematica&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgAToICCEQFhAdEB46BwghEAoQoAFQkosCWOGeAmCZowJoAXAAeACAAZwMiAGsHpIBCTAuNy41LjgtMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjlttzw3IPxAhVnh_0HHT8UAxwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) or multidimensional optimization in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and time! I guess you more or less mentioned about the important side questions connected to my main question, it is helpful! However, I think it will need a good amount of reading. Also, I knew about some of them , but my understanding is they are are not very much related to my main problem. But I can be wrong.